# Why isn't javafx on the default classpath even when I have installed Oracle JDK 1.8?

Tags: java, javafx, classpath, java-8

I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8.0.45 on Kubuntu Linux which I installed following [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04) instructions. I had to do the manual install since the automatic one didn't work.

Even with the Oracle JDK I still can't use javafx without manually setting the classpath. What could cause javafx to not be on the default classpath as it should be in 1.8?

EDIT:  `Java -version` in terminal gives:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I am developing under ubuntu 14.04 and gentoo. Both have Oracle JDK 1.8 installed. I cannot reproduce this problem. I think something with your setup is faulty.

Comment: OK, maybe a reinstall then? I'm using a chromebook so I'm running Linux with crouton:
https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton

Comment: This is the wrong platform to ask such questions. You may want to try your luck at [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Then I will refer to askubuntu instead. Thanks

Comment: What are you setting the classpath to, to make it work?

Comment: Please add the output of `java -version` to your question.

Comment: @James_D In the terminal I type the classpath like this:
    javac -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/jre/lib/ext/jxrt.jar TestPoint2D.java'

Comment: Please add the output of `javac -version` to your question.

Comment: Btw. what issues did you have with the PPA? It's really the most convenient way to install and update Oracle Java on Kubuntu and it helps with environment variables, too.

Comment: @Puce for some reason the java installer would not download. I want to recreate the error to show you, could this cause problems since I have java already installed?

Comment: This question has been answered at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/609951/javafx-is-not-on-the-default-classpath-even-with-oracle-jdk-1-8/609954)